# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" when using momentjs with ASP5/MVC6

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, momentjs

When I try to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), installed through bower, my web app runs into the following error when the javascript file for moment is attempted to be loaded:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

On this line:

`import { hooks as moment, setHookCallback } from './lib/utils/hooks';`

I am using ASP5, MVC6, Visual Studio 2015 Community. Couldn't find any answers to this here or on documentation from momentjs.

My script tag looks like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/moment/src/moment.js"></script>`

Comment: you need to compile moment now, they switched to ES6. premature imho...

Comment: yup agreed on the premature, and this is the exact reason why! You'll need to use babel or something like it, to transpile the code down to ES5 for this to work, simple as that lol

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like they include a built version of it already. I was using the `src` version, which isn't compiled. Just point to the `min` version and it'll be there, which is compiled.